# ArrayBuffer to QByteArray conversion failes for QT 6.5.2

Tags: c++, qt, qml, arraybuffer, qbytearray

In following code snippets, I try to transfer an `ArrayBuffer` from QML to a C++ handler, where it is supposed to get converted into a `QByteArray`. This is working in QT 6.5.1 but stopped working in 6.5.2.

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQuickItem>

#include "ComboBoxHandler.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    // register the class with the QML engine
    auto handler = new ComboBoxHandler();
    qmlRegisterSingletonInstance("ComboBoxHandler", 1, 0, "ComboBoxHandler", handler);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreationFailed,
    &app, []() { QCoreApplication::exit(-1); },
    Qt::QueuedConnection);

    const QUrl url(u"qrc:/TestBench/main.qml"_qs);
    engine.load(url);
    return app.exec();

}
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Window
import QtQuick.Controls

import ComboBoxHandler

ApplicationWindow
{
    id: mainWindow
    width: 600
    height: 400
    visible: true

    Button {
        text: "test"

        onClicked: {
            // fill in some data into the ArrayBuffer
            let data = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
                data.push(i);
            }
            // send ArrayBuffer to handler
            ComboBoxHandler.onItemChanged(data)
        }
     }
}
```

**ComboBoxHandler.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <QObject>
#include <QDebug>

class ComboBoxHandler: public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
public slots:
    void onItemChanged(const QByteArray& newValue) {
        // I would expect the data here.
        // works in QT 6.5.1 and stopped working in 6.5.2
        qDebug() << "Value: " << newValue;
    }
};
```

Can anyone confirm, that this is not working in 6.5.2?
Has anyone a fix or a workaround for this?
Is this a QT regression bug?

Comment: It sounds like a bug to me, though you never actually define what "not working" means. Does newValue have anything in it at all?

Comment: Yes. newValue is empty when running with 6.5.2. With 6.5.1 the QByteArray contains the elements.

Comment: In QML/JS the thing you're declaring is a QVariantList not an ArrayBuffer.

If you set your C++ type to QVariant you can confirm whether you're getting either a QVariantList or an QByteArray and react accordingly to either or both.

It's probably better this way, since, you can coerce/cast/convert the incoming object and do appropriate conversions.

Comment: If I change the type to QVariantList in the slot, the data is coming through. This seems to be a acceptable workaround. Still, it feels like a bug that the type conversion is not longer working for type QByteArray.

Comment: Added a bug for this:  https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-116701

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known bug (https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-115733) and is fixed in 6.5.3.